# jQuery: Change "action" based on Select value

Tags: jquery, html

I've made this code which changes the second select based on what you select in the first select.

But now I need a way in jQuery to also change the "form action" based on what is selected on the first select.

I want `action="renault.php"` if option 1 is selected and I want `action="citroen.php"` if option 2 is selected on the first select.

I also want to be required both selects, so its mandatory to select at least one option on each select, and if someone doesnt do that and hit submit then an alert should tell them "please select at least one brand and one model"

I've tried several codes but couldnt get this to work.

Also if the person selects "select a model" or "select a brand" the alert should also appear (requesting to select at least one model and brand)

Can someone help here?

Code:

```
<form id="frmPreselect" name="frmPreselect" method="post" action="">

    <p>
    <select name="selectOne" id="selectOne" style="font-size:16px; margin-right:20px;     font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
      <option value="">-- select a Brand --</option>
<option value="1">Renault</option>
<option value="2">Cïtroen</option>
</select>


<select name="selectTwo" id="selectTwo" style="font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
<option value="">-- select a model --</option>
</select>
  </p>
  <p>
 <input type="submit" value="SOLICITAR PRESUPUESTOS" style="font-size:20px; font-    family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold" />
  </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#selectOne').change(function() {
var options = '';
if($(this).val() == '1') {
options = '<option value="clio">clio</option><option value="symbol">symbol</option>        <option value="sandero">sandero</option>';
}
else if ($(this).val() == '2'){
options = '<option value="Berlingo">Berlingo</option><option value="C3">C3</option>    <option value="C4">C4</option>';
}
$('#selectTwo').html(options);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/// <reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js" />
/// <reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    var actions = new Array();
    actions[1] = "renault";
    actions[2] = "citroen";


    $("select").change(function () {
        if ($("select#selectOne").val() != "" &&
            $("select#selectTwo").val() != "" ) {
            $("form").attr("action", 
              actions[$("select#selectOne").val()] + ".php");
        }
    });

    $("form").submit(function (event) {

        if ($("select#selectOne").val() == "" || 
            $("select#selectTwo").val() == "") {
            alert("Select a model & brand");
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: this was clean and to the point and worked exactly as i needed

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you!  Some of the other answers have other good techniques you may want to incorporate as well.

Comment: Should be `actions[1] = "renault";` and `actions[2] = "citroen";` if the used webserver is on a case-sensitive OS

Answer (score 2):

You can also wait with setting your action until you submit the form:

```
$('#frmPreselect').submit(function (e) { 
     var sel1 = $('#selectOne');
     var sel2 = $('#selectTwo');

     if (sel1[0].selectedIndex == 0 || sel2[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
          e.preventDefault(); //don't submit
          alert('You forget something!'); //alert
          return;
     }

     var frm = $(this);

     if (sel1.val() == 1)
        frm.attr('action', 'http://blabla'); //set some action

     //etc. etc.


     //in the end it will submit the form.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("selectOne").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val())
    {
       case "1" : $("form[name='frmPreselect']").attr("action","http://foo"); break;
       case "2" : $("form[name='frmPreselect']").attr("action","http://bar"); break;
       default : $("form[name='frmPreselect']").attr("action","http://foo");
     }
});
```

You could use either `form[name='frmPreselect'`] to select the form or `#frmPreselect` of course, but I wouldn't use just `$("form")` as that will cause you problems if you add a second form to the page 2 months down the road.

Comment: Wouldn't the values in the switch actually be "1", "2"?

Comment: Whoops yes they would - sorry didn't check what he had actually put in the option values

Answer (score 1):

Complete example below, but even if I don't see the code, I'm pretty sure `citroen.php` and `renault.php` are not so different so I would advise using a `car.php` handling brand and model.

PS: you should take a look at some non intrusive validation plugin (see this [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html) for example)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 4117106</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectOne').change(function() {
            var options = '<option value="0">-- select a model --</option>';

            if($(this).val() == '1') {
                options += '<option value="clio">clio</option>';
                options += '<option value="symbol">symbol</option>';
                options += '<option value="sandero">sandero</option>';
            } else if ($(this).val() == '2'){
                options += '<option value="Berlingo">Berlingo</option>';
                options += '<option value="C3">C3</option>';
                options += '<option value="C4">C4</option>';
            } 

            $('#selectTwo').html(options);
        });

        $('#frmPreselect').submit(function() {
            if ($('#selectOne').val() == '0' || $('#selectTwo').val() == '0') {
                alert('please select at least one brand and one model');
                return false; // don't submit
            }

            var action = '';

            if($('#selectOne').val() == '1') {
                action = 'renault.php';
            } else if ($('#selectOne').val() == '2'){
                action = 'citroen.php';
            }

            $(this).attr('action', action);
            return true; // submit
        });

        $('#selectOne').change();
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        select, .bigSubmit {
            font-size: 16px; 
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }

        #selectOne {
            margin-right: 20px; 
        }

        .bigSubmit {
            font-size: 20px; 
            font-weight:bold;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmPreselect" name="frmPreselect" method="post" action="">
        <p>
            <select name="selectOne" id="selectOne">
                <option value="0">-- select a Brand --</option>
                <option value="1">Renault</option>
                <option value="2">Cïtroen</option>
            </select>

            <select name="selectTwo" id="selectTwo">
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SOLICITAR PRESUPUESTOS" class="bigSubmit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im curious about your suggestion of using car.php, i would love to centralize like that but the problem is that i have different forms on renault.php citroen.php etc so i would have to build car.php dynamically? with the proper form according to the selected brand i guess?

Comment: @sebastian, something like that yes, but you can `include` the specific part (forms in you case). My point was that you should avoid duplicate code